# MYSQL: How to get results of records that dont exists (NOT EXISTS) on a list of users entries

Tags: mysql, not-exists

For each day, users are expected to capture a timesheet entry.

The result set needs to obtain a list of users, and any dates, that the user has NOT captured a timesheet entry for within that current month.

as an example of an ideal result set for November 2022:

```
UserName | MissedDates
-----------------------
Joe       | 2022-11-20
Joe       | 2022-11-26
Joe       | 2022-11-27
Billy     | 2022-11-02
Billy     | 2022-11-09
etc       | etc
etc       | etc
```

Started by creating a reference TEMPORARY TABLE that has a result list of all the expected days for that month, so that it could be used against all the date records the user has captured for that month. Can do this by checking what records dont exist (NOT EXISTS) in the DBTable compared to the months dates records in the TempTable.

```
SET @current_date:=CURDATE();
SET @StartDate:=date_add(date_add(LAST_DAY(@current_date),interval 1 DAY),interval -1 MONTH);
SET @EndDate:=LAST_DAY(@current_date);

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE MonthlyDatesTbl
WITH RECURSIVE `MonthlyDates` AS
(
   SELECT @StartDate AS `day` 
   
   UNION ALL 
   
   SELECT date_add(`day`,interval 1 DAY) AS `day` FROM `MonthlyDates` WHERE `day` < @EndDate
)
SELECT * FROM `MonthlyDates`;


SELECT `MonthlyDatesTbl`.day FROM `MonthlyDatesTbl` 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM timesheet_entry WHERE timesheet_entry.user_id = 83 AND timesheet_entry.timesheet_entry_date = MonthlyDatesTbl.day);

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE MonthlyDatesTbl;
```

The above query results the below for user id 83:

```
day 
--------
2022-11-20
2022-11-26
2022-11-27
```

Which correctly details the dates the user did not capture entries for.... but

MAIN Q: How would one now apply this logic to be queried on all users and not just one?

Might be a case of staring at the problem too long that im missing something simple!?

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have a users-table containing the username. You can then do:

```
SELECT u.UserName, m.day 
FROM MonthlyDatesTbl m
  JOIN users u on 1=1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT * 
  FROM timesheet_entry e 
  WHERE e.user_id = u.id AND e.timesheet_entry_date = m.day
);
```